# Android Custom ListView item unclickable

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a custom listView that I'm populating with this item layout. The problem is that the OnItemClickListener even handler of ListView only captures clicks on the imageView, but not on the other 2 textViews. Anyway to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Fourdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Fourdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Fourdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Fourdp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Fourdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Fourdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Fourdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Fourdp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#336699" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried setting android:focusable="false" and android:clickable="false" to the ImageView, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the LinearLayout containing the TextViews has the `android:longClickable="true"` attribute.

It works if you remove it.

Why do you need it ? You can use the `setOnLongClickListener()` method of the ListView to detect long clicks on items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a onclicklistner for the items in your adapter (where you inflate the row view)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

             View v = convertView;
             if (v == null) 
             {
                 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)InAppPurchaseActivity.this.getParent().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_product, null);
             }

            // add your view with onclicklistner here


             return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

//add this line in your both textview `android:duplicateParentState="true"` this will work.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textColor="#336699" />
    </LinearLayout>
```